# How to register a Red Hat 5.9 System

Tags: rhel

I am wondering if someone has a workaround for the following:

I am re-establishing a Red Hat subscription for an i386_64 based system.

The subscription is purchased, and I've had a Red Hat account for over a decade, so all fine there.

I received a confirmation email giving me information about the subscription, and the entitlement shows up on the Red Hat site.

However, the activation information I was sent in the email is not in the form the web-based activation expects, and trying to install subscription-manager fails due to missing dependencies. I cannot go fetch those dependencies, because I cannot register either on the server or on the web site.

Here is the output from trying to unpack and install subscription-manager

```
[root@h2oamr subscription-manager]# tar xvf registration_update-rhel-5-rhsm.tar.gz && rpm -Uvh *.rpm --replacefiles
python-dateutil-1.2-3.el5.noarch.rpm
python-rhsm-1.11.3-5.el5.x86_64.rpm
subscription-manager-1.11.3-10.el5.x86_64.rpm
subscription-manager-firstboot-1.11.3-10.el5.x86_64.rpm
subscription-manager-gui-1.11.3-10.el5.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        python-simplejson is needed by python-rhsm-1.11.3-5.el5.x86_64
        python-ethtool is needed by subscription-manager-1.11.3-10.el5.x86_64
        virt-what is needed by subscription-manager-1.11.3-10.el5.x86_64
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Yes, I do have a support ticket entered with all these updates and a sosreport.

Edit to answer the answer.

yum yields the same kind of error that started off this quest. Where are the CentOS repositories for version 5, and what are the paths? I'll try that.

```
[root@h2oamr ~]# yum install python-simplejson
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
There was an error communicating with RHN.
RHN Satellite or RHN Classic support will be disabled.

Error Message:
    Service not enabled for system profile: "h2oamr.Arlington1.local"
Error Class Code: 31
Error Class Info: 
     This system does not have a valid entitlement for Red Hat Network.
     Please visit https://rhn.redhat.com/rhn/systems/SystemEntitlements.do
     or login at https://rhn.redhat.com, and from the "Your RHN" tab,
     select "Subscription Management" to enable RHN service for this system.
Explanation:
    Your organization does not have enough Management entitlements to register this
    system to Red Hat Network. Please notify your organization administrator of this error. 
    You should be able to register this system after your organization frees existing 
    or purchases additional entitlements. Additional entitlements may be purchased by your
    organization administrator by logging into Red Hat Network and visiting
    the 'Subscription Management' page in the 'Your RHN' section of RHN.

    A common cause of this error code is due to having mistakenly setup an
    Activation Key which is set as the universal default.  If an activation key is set
    on the account as a universal default, you can disable this key and retry to avoid
    requiring a Management entitlement.
Setting up Install Process
No package python-simplejson available.
Nothing to do
[root@h2oamr ~]#
```

***Epilogue:***

I followed Red Hat's instructions for using up2date to register the system, and was stymied, because I could not connect to their repository. I re-tried today, and am updating.

One thing I learned, though. Once you've purchased a subscription, you own it with no refund, even if you cannot make use of the subscription, like being able to activate it, and I purchased the subscription through a reseller.

I followed this [link](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/11216) in order to use up2date to activate the subscription.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the dependencies?

RHEL 5.9 is in End of Production Phase 3.  Therefore `yum` should be operational.

First try to get the dependencies with `yum`, RedHat should still provide them from the repositories since they're dependencies of the subscription manager.  In other words:

```
yum install python-simplejson
yum install python-ethtool
yum install virt-what
```

If `yum` is not operational keep reading.

I do not have a RHEL 5 running.  But I could find the needed RPMs quite easily from the CentOS repositories.

- [python-simplejson](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/5.11/x86_64/CentOS/python-simplejson-2.0.9-8.el5.x86_64.html)
- [python-ethtool](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/5.11/x86_64/CentOS/python-ethtool-0.6-5.el5.x86_64.html)
- [virt-what](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/5.11/x86_64/CentOS/virt-what-1.11-2.el5.x86_64.html)

`python-rhsm` appears to be bundled with the registration update, so you already have that.

Comment: @ThomasDickey - yep, it was a good point.  I upgraded all my RHEL machines long ago, so I'm not keeping track. Thanks for that.  (answer amended, misleading comment removed.)

Comment: Thanks, but yum returns an error that I'm not registered. Should I be switching repositories, and how is that done?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus - If `yum` is not operational you need to use the plain RPMs (seriously, download and install them, they're RPMs), that's why i added them to the answer.